# How to add an onClickListener to different items in a ListView row

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, onclicklistener

So I'm making an app where one of the features is you are able to set alerts. Below are 2 example alerts that I used an adapter to put into a ListView. Each item has an ImageView, a TextView, and another ImageView.

[image]

My question is how would I turn on a `onClickListener` for the different images and maybe even the text depending how I do things.

For example, when you click the 'x' it will delete that alert from the list (showing me how to do and letting the adapter know a alert was deleted would be cool) or clicking the alert picture would activate/deactivate the alert (which would switch between the two images seen).

This screen comes to be by a `MainActivity` inflating an `AlertFragment`. In the past I've had problems with Fragments implementing inner classes but the way I have it set up now is (I think) with Fragments implementing inner classes. This is what I currently have which I know is wrong:

```
public class AlertsFragment extends Fragment {

    private ListView mListView;
    private List<Alert> alerts = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_alerts, container, false);

        mListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.alerts_list_view);

        alerts.add(new Alert(1, 5400, true));
        alerts.add(new Alert(2, 120, false));

        AlertsAdapter adapter = new AlertsAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.alert_item_row, alerts);
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        getActivity().setTitle(new AlertsItem().getLabel());

        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
                Log.d("matt", "list_item");
                ImageView img = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.active_image);
                img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Log.d("matt", "image");
                        alerts.get(position).setActive(!alerts.get(position).isActive());
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Any help you guys can give would be appreciated, thanks.

--------------------------------------------------------- EDIT ---------------------------------------------------------

As some have requested, here is my ArrayAdapter code:

```
/**
 * Adapter for adding Alerts to ListView
 */
public class AlertsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    private int resource;
    List<Alert> objects;

    public AlertsAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Alert> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.resource = resource;
        this.objects = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        AlertHolder holder = null;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)getContext()).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);

            holder = new AlertHolder();
                holder.imgActive = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.active_image);
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txt_title);
            holder.txtTime = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txt_time);

            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (AlertHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        Alert alert = (Alert) getItem(position);
        int image;
        if (alert.isActive()) {
            image = R.drawable.ic_alert_active_medium;
        }
        else {
            image = R.drawable.ic_alert_inactive_medium;
        }

        holder.imgActive.setImageResource(image);
        holder.txtTitle.setText("Route " + Integer.toString(alert.getRoute()));

        int min = alert.getTime() / 60;
        int hr = min / 60;
        min = min % 60;

        holder.txtTime.setText(((hr == 0) ? "" : (Integer.toString(hr) + " hr ")) + Integer.toString(min) + " min ");

        return row;
    }

    private static class AlertHolder {
        ImageView imgActive;
        TextView txtTitle;
        TextView txtTime;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have your try Adding `android:gravity="center"` to `GridView`?

Comment: That's not what I'm asking, I'm asking how to set up an onClickListener for the images.

Comment: Add your custom ArrayAdapter code. When you inflate the different parts of a row item add the OnClickListeners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your own `Adapter` which extends the `ArrayAdapter` (see [this link](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)), override the `getView()` method and in there you can add `OnClickListener`s to every `View` in the `ListView`'s child. To notify the `ListView` a child is removed, call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the `ListView`'s `Adapter`.

You could solve this using the `ListView`, but I would suggest using the `RecyclerView` ([Android RecyclerView](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html)). `RecyclerView` has better support for updating its children (like removing, inserting, updating children) and has default animations set.

Comment: How would I remove an item from the ListView's data set from within these? For instance when I click the x I want it to be deleted. I've almost got it but it get's messed up over time of adding and removing alerts.

Comment: In addition, `RecyclerView`'s lack of an `OnItemClickListener` was for this very reason, I believe. It's intended to be set up manually so that cases like this can be handled.

Answer (score 0):

You have to manage click listener in AlertsAdapter class for separate views like x button, image.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this in onClick method.Example;

```
 public MyViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        iconImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.myRecyclerImageView);
        iconTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.myRecyclerTextView);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        iconTextView.setOnClickListener(this);
        iconImageView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
    } 

    // onClick Listener for view 
    @Override 
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v.getId() == iconTextView.getId()){
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "ITEM PRESSED = " + String.valueOf(getAdapterPosition()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else { 
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "ROW PRESSED = " + String.valueOf(getAdapterPosition()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using in this snippet the same situation, when I clicked on the row, I save the position into my holder. I think you can use the same code, changing a little part of this code.

```
public class DeliveryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Delivery> {

    public DeliveryAdapter(Context context, List<Delivery> objects) {
        super(context, 0, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        ViewHolder holder;

        if (null == convertView) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.list_item_delivery,
                    parent,
                    false);

            holder.tvName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
            holder.ivCheck = convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivCheck);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Delivery item = getItem(position);

        holder.tvName.setText(item.getName());
        holder.ivCheck.setVisibility((item.isCheckVisible()) ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        holder.position = position;

        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
                for (int i = 0; i< getCount(); i++){
                    Delivery currentItem = getItem(i);
                    currentItem.setCheckVisible(viewHolder.position == i);
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder{
        public ImageView ivCheck;
        public TextView tvName;

        int position;

    }
}
```